# dysplay data to database from excel file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-excel

I'm trying to export the data from the database to excel with laravel 5.0.
To achieve this I use a stored procedure to get data.

```
BEGIN
        SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = (3*1024);
        SET @SQL = NULL;
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
            CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN se.date_seance = ', CONCAT('\'',se.date_seance,'\'') ,
            ' AND v.faux_gout = ',CONCAT('\'',v.faux_gout,'\''),
            ' THEN uv.point END) '
            , CONCAT('\'',DATE_FORMAT(se.date_seance,'%d-%M-%Y'),'\''), CONCAT('\'faux_gout:',v.faux_gout,'\'') ))
            INTO @SQL 
            FROM user_verre uv
                LEFT JOIN users u ON uv.user_id = u.id 
                    LEFT JOIN verres v ON uv.verre_id = v.id
                        LEFT JOIN series s ON v.serie_id = s.id
                            LEFT JOIN seances se ON se.id = s.seance_id
                                WHERE v.est_faux = 1 AND se.statut = 1 AND se.etablissement_id = _labo AND (se.date_seance BETWEEN _debut AND _fin);

        #SELECT @SQL 'jour-2';
        SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT u.name,', IFNULL(@SQL,'u.name ') ,
                                'FROM user_verre uv
                                    LEFT JOIN users u ON uv.user_id = u.id
                                        LEFT JOIN verres v ON uv.verre_id = v.id
                                            LEFT JOIN series s ON v.serie_id = s.id
                                                LEFT JOIN seances se ON se.id = s.seance_id
                                                    WHERE v.est_faux = 1 AND se.statut = 1 AND se.etablissement_id = ',_labo,' AND (se.date_seance BETWEEN ', '\'',_debut,'\'' , ' AND ' ,'\'',_fin,'\'' ,')
                                                            GROUP BY u.name');

        PREPARE stmt FROM  @SQL;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

and the php code belows

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
        return Excel::create('performance '.join('-',$date), function($excel) use ($usines,$date , $alphabet){
            $excel->setTitle('performance');
            $pas = 0;
            foreach ($usines as $usine_id) {
                //Call the stored process 
                $result = DB::select("CALL performance_month(?, ?, ?)",[$date[0],$date[1],$usine_id]);
                $labo = Etablissement::find($usine_id);
                $data  = array();
                if(count($result)!=0){
                    //build the table to display in the excel file
                    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                        $ligne = get_object_vars($value);
                        $entete = array();
                        foreach($ligne as $k => $l){
                            array_push($entete , $k);
                        }
                        $pas = count($entete);
                        array_push($entete , '% DETECTION');
                        $data [] = $entete;
                        break;
                    }

                    $line = 4;
                    $lettre = $alphabet[$pas-1];
                    foreach ($result as $y => $val) {
                        $val  = (array) $val;
                        array_push($val,'=SUM(B'.$line.':'.$lettre.$line.')/COUNTA(B'.$line.':'.$lettre.$line.')*100');
                        $data [] = $val;
                        $line++;
                    }
                }

                $excel->sheet($labo->nom, function($sheet) use($data) {
                    $sheet->fromArray($data,null,'A3',true,false);
                });
            }   
        })->download('xlsx');
```

**the screenshoot belows show the good result in dev environment**
[image: Test in dev environment]

**but when i deploy on server i get this result**
[image: reslt in prod environment]

**in dev environment i use mysql 5.7.21**

**library for excel export "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",**

**in prod environment i use mysql 5.6.17**

**but when i call the procedure in phpMyAdmin (prod and dev) i get the same result**

someone has an idea of ​​the cause of malfunctioning??

Comment: Try to open your excel with notpad++, sometime you can see php error ...

Comment: the file is not readable and I can not even get the errors